# Whats the correct way to add easy_install-2.7 bin after successful install of 3.3?

Tags: python, easy-install

Python's [Easy Install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) ain't that easy. The [instructions from python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) offer a command which pipes in the python version into the installer. Only after installing did I learn about easy_install and ["Multiple Python Versions"](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#multiple-python-versions). I thought I was covered because according to *this page* easy_install is supposed to support multiple versions of python with the command `easy_install-x.y`

Looking in the bin directory I have `/usr/bin/easy_install-3.3` which works for python3.3 and `/usr/bin/easy_install` which works for...3.3! Where's `easy_install-2.7`? Clearly it wasn't installed because the *other page* offers the easy install instructions to 'downloads the appropriate version' for your python install. The two instructions contradict.

So what do I do now?

Comment: Did you try running it with Python 2.7?

Comment: I figured it out as I was writing the question. I was so annoyed at python.org, and all the time I wasted figuring it out, and not finding the same question here, I figured if it saved someone else's time its a good Q. Besides, at 70 reputation I needed the 2pts. And by the looks of it Voodoo didn't do too bad either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your environment's "python" command launched python3.x. If so, easy_install is installed into the python version you selected, so when you did this:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

you probably should have specified python2.7 like this:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python2.7
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks.